# SP 2013 Search PDF junk text

Tags: search, search-results

I have few PDF documents that are scanned and stored in document library. When I search for the document the search results description contains some junk text 'I D D I ^" as shown below and also the word "Commissioner" is spelled as "Gommissioner" which is bit strange.

Any suggestons?

[image]

Comment: What version of SharePoint? What are you using for Scanning? Are you doing OCR? Have you tried opening the file and search for the misspellings? (SharePoint just uses what ever text is available, so I suspect it is in your OCR software.)

Comment: SharePoint 2013 enterprise(on premise). Not sure about the OCR software used to scan... I copied some text from the pdf document to notepad and noticed that the work commissioner is copied as Gommissioner in notepad... I also suspect something wrong with Scanning software...

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint just uses what is provided as text in the document, so if you don't do OCR you won't get any content. If you do use OCR, the accuracy will impact your search experience. I wrote a post a while back about "testing" your iFilters. SharePoint 2013 does not use an iFilter for PDF any more, but you can still use one to test your OCR software. Try this: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2011/09/28/troubleshooting-ifilters-and-crawled-properties/